# UPDATE/INSERT based on non-unique keys?

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have a table that contains

```
id | user | date | data1 | data2 ......
```

where `id` is the primary unique key.

I'm trying to write a query that can UPDATE if both `user` and `date` exist while INSERT if either one of them doesn't exist

I thought about the INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY...UPDATE method, but that requires using the unique key, which I do have but not using.

What would be a good way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Have you tried making `(user, date)` a unique key? This may still trigger the `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` method correctly.

Comment: @cyberbit that's actually an awesome idea! I think I can try implementing this way.

Comment: Hopefully it works. Let us know. ;)

Comment: I did a test with a small set of data. It seems like things are working in the expected way.

Comment: Cool! I'll add an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per discussion in comments, you should **make `(user, date)` a unique key.**

This will trigger the `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query as expected, updating rows with matching `user` and `date` fields, and inserting new ones where no match is found.

Answer (score 0):

The only valid option is to implement this `UPSERT` in the programming language that you use with mysql, because MySQL needs a unique key for both `INSERT ... INTO` and [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html).

Or to add a unique index on the `user` and `date` columns which seems to be in concordance with your business logic anyway.